# match.. against

Tags: mysql, select, against

My query is not working, it always show related 0. Even against data do exist.

```
 SELECT number, MATCH(number) 
 AGAINST('02' '01' '03' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
 as related FROM lottery_entries;
```

you can see the result below.

[image]

i don't know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is because MySQL has a server parameter - [The minimum length of the word to be included in a FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len). Default value for this parameter is 4 so your words like 'XX' are not included in this index. You should change this system parameter, restart server and then rebuild all FULLTEXT indexes.

```
REPAIR TABLE lottery_entries QUICK;
```

- [Change the full text index minimum word length with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-full-text-index-word-length/)

Comment: thank you for the nice help, but i couldn't locate my.cnf file. I am using wamp. can you help in setting "ft_min_word_len" value, specially when I am using shared server.